# pandas groupby.apply to pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following custom function to make aggregation in my pandas dataframe, and I want to do the same things in pyspark:

```py
def custom_aggregation_pyspark(x,queries):
    names={}
    for k, v in regles_calcul.items():
        plus = x.query(v["plus_credit"])['OBNETCRE'].sum() + x.query(v["plus_debit"])['OBNETDEB'].sum()
        minus = x.query(v["minus_credit"])['OBNETCRE'].sum() + x.query(v["minus_debit"])['OBNETDEB'].sum()  

     

        names[k]= plus-minus
    return pd.Series(names, index=list(names.keys()))


df = df.groupby(['LBUDG']).apply(custom_aggregation_pandas, queries ).sum()
```

were queries is a dictionary of query like

```py
{'first_queries': {   
    'plus_credit': "classe_compte_rg2 in ('237', '238')",
    'plus_debit': "classe_compte_rg2 in ('237', '238')", 
    'minus_credit': "classe_compte_rg2 in ('237', '238')", 
    'minus_debit': "classe_compte_rg1 in ('20', '21', '23')"
     }
}
```

So, I replaced the pandas "query" by pyspark 'sql'

```py
def custom_aggregation_pyspark(x,queries):
    x.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
    names={}
    for k , v in queries.items():
        plus = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE "+ v["plus_credit"]).select('OBNETCRE').groupby('OBNETCRE').sum().collect() + spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE "+ v["plus_debit"]).select('OBNETDEB').groupby('OBNETDEB').sum().collect() 
        minus= spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE "+ v["minus_credit"]).select('OBNETCRE').groupby('OBNETCRE').sum().collect() + spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df WHERE "+ v["minus_debit"]).select('OBNETDEB').groupby('OBNETDEB').sum().collect() 
        names[k]= plus-minus
    return pd.Series(names, index=list(names.keys()))

df.groupby("LBUDG").agg(custom_aggregation_pyspark(df,queries))
```

I am certainly going in the wrong direction as the above code do not work, could you please guide me where I should look at?

The desired output is a table grouped by `LBUDG` (a string) and other columns use custom aggregation functions.

Edit Dataframe Sample:

| LBUDG | OBNETCRE | OBNETDEB | classe_compte_rg0 | classe_compte_rg1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LE POIZAT | 0,00 | 0,00 | 1 | 10 |
| LE POIZAT | 67572,00 | 0,00 | 1 | 10 |
| LE POIZAT | 0,00 | 0,00 | 1 | 10 |
| LE POIZAT | 4908,12 | 0,00 | 1 | 10 |
| LE POIZAT | 0,00 | 0,00 | 1 | 10 |
| DAFOUR | 295240,67 | 0,00 | 1 | 10 |
| LE POIZAT | 0,00 | 0,00 | 1 | 11 |
| LE POIZAT | 0,00 | 0,00 | 1 | 12 |
| LE POIZAT | 0,00 | 0,00 | 1 | 13 |
| LE POIZAT | 0,00 | 0,00 | 1 | 13 |
| LE POIZAT | 53697,94 | 0,00 | 1 | 13 |

Expected output:

| LBUDG | AGG1 | AGG2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LE POIZAT | agg1_value for LE POIZAT | ... |
| DAFOUR | .... | ... |

where agg1 corresponds (for example), to the sum of `OBNETCRE - OBNETDEB`, where `classe_compte_rg1` has value, is 10 or 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `epxr` to evaluate the conditions passed in the `queries` dict and use a conditional aggregation to calculate the sum. Here's an example that is equivalent to the one you gave in pandas :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


def custom_aggregation_pyspark(df, regles_calcul):
    df1 = df.groupBy("LBUDG") \
        .agg(
        *[
            ((F.sum(F.when(F.expr(v["plus_credit"]), F.col("OBNETCRE")).otherwise(0)) +
              F.sum(F.when(F.expr(v["plus_debit"]), F.col("OBNETDEB")).otherwise(0))) -
             (F.sum(F.when(F.expr(v["minus_credit"]), F.col("OBNETCRE")).otherwise(0)) +
              F.sum(F.when(F.expr(v["minus_debit"]), F.col("OBNETDEB")).otherwise(0)))
             ).alias(k)

            for k, v in regles_calcul.items()
        ]
    )

    return df1


df = custom_aggregation_pyspark(df, queries)
```